# Find and replace data in file (without loading the entire thing)?

Tags: c#, file, replace

I want to replace some data in a file, however I do not know exactly where this 200MB file would contain it. Is it possible to find (and replace them with something else) these values without loading a 200mb+ file into the memory?

Comment: @alykins The file would unfortunately be an .exe. What i am trying to do is kind of a "patching" process.

Comment: Are you 100% sure an exe? How would an exe be storing data?

Comment: @alykins for example there's the original exe, then there is the new binary with minor (few kilobytes) of change. Now instead of, let's say for example if this was a game i wouldn't make the user re download all the 200mb but only the patch with info on what bytes to change. sorry english isn't my first language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching the file is not a problem. What you need is to work with the FileStream which is available via [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.File.Open(v=vs.100).aspx) method. You can read through the file up to the bytes you need to replace.
Problem arises when you need to insert something. The FileStream allows you to overwrite some or all of the file contents from a particular byte forth and to append new content to its end but it does not allow you to insert data in the middle of the file. In order to overcome this problem you are going to need a temporary file. If you agree to that you could do the following:

1. Open the FileStream on the original file.
2. Create a temporary file that will hold the draft version.
3. Search through the original file and copy all "good" data into temporary file up to the point where modifications are to be made.
4. Insert modified and new data into the temporary file.
5. Finish up the temporary file with the remaining "good" content from the original file.
6. Replace the original file with the temporary one.
7. Delete the temporary file.

You could use the [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename(v=vs.100).aspx) method for convenient way of utilizing a temporary file.

P.S. If you modify an exe then you probably make replacements on text constants and you neither need to insert new bytes nor to remove any. In such a case you do not need to bother with the temporary file and the FileStream is all you need.

P.P.S. Working with the FileStream you decide on size of a buffer you read from file and write back. Keep in mind that this size is the tradeoff between memory consumption, I/O performance and complexity of your code. Choose wisely. I would make it per-byte for the first time and try to optimize increasing the buffer to say 64k when it works. You can count on the FileStream to buffer data; it is not performing disk I/O each time you request another byte from it. If you dive into buffering yourself then try not to fragment the [Large Object Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx). The threshold for .NET 4.5 is 85000 bytes.

Comment: Alykins, you are wrong. Files are a mere storage of binary data. It does not matter what the contents are and it does not matter what the file name extension is you can freely work with the file contents.

Comment: Cool- I never knew you could modify an executable via this access method. I was trying to find documentation one way or the other- but I'll trust as your answer seems on point for question.

Answer (score 1):

Just a thought, how about reading your file line by line or may be in chunk of bytes and see in each chunk if u have the data that needs to be replaced. Also while reading make sure get the file pointer till where you have read the file so that when u find the match then u can go back to that location and over write those exact bytes which u have targetted.

Comment: Maybe this would work. The exe would most likely break but opening chunks is an option i guess...